# Why can't I create a button on Phaserjs?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to make a button:

```
 this.add.button(0, 0, 'button-deposit', actionOnClick, this, 1, 0, 2);
```

**But the error pops up: this.add.button is not a function**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK the button class like in Phaser v2 is not present in Phaser3, for unknown reasons. In my [Phaser3 example game](https://github.com/BdR76/Phaser3-example-game) on github I've added an `addButton` prototype to `Scene` to be able to use buttons again.

See code below:

```
// include code below in separate .js file
// add a button to a scene
Phaser.Scene.prototype.addButton = function(x, y, key, callback, callbackContext, overFrame, outFrame, downFrame, upFrame)
{
        // add a button
        var btn = this.add.sprite(x, y, key, outFrame).setInteractive();
        btn.on('pointerover', function (ptr, x, y) { this.setFrame(overFrame) } );
        btn.on('pointerout',  function (ptr)       { this.setFrame(outFrame) } );
        btn.on('pointerdown', function (ptr)       { this.setScale(0.9, 0.9) } );
        btn.on('pointerup', callback.bind(callbackContext));

        return btn;
};

// in a scene you can then do this
var mybutton = this.addButton(100, 100, 'mysprites', this.doButtonAction, this, 'btn_play_hl', 'btn_play', 'btn_play_hl', 'btn_play');
```